# How to stream OpenGL rendered scene from the cloud to remote clients

Tags: opengl, 3d, cloud, webrtc

So I have a desktop app, using OpenGL to render large data sets in 3D. I want to move it to the cloud and use server-side rendering in order to stream the rendered images to remote clients (JS, etc.).
From what I understand, WebRTC is the best approach for that. However, it's complicated and expensive to implement, and mainly aimed for video conferencing applications. Are there any frameworks/open source which are more suitable for 3D graphics streaming. Is Nvidia's GameStreaming a suitable technology to explore or is it tailored for games? Any other ideas and approaches?

Comment: Wondering to know why this good question got negative?!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ideas and approaches, and which one works best depends a lot on your particular application, budget, client, and server.

If you render on the server side, the big advantage is that you control the GPU, the available memory, the OS and driver version, etc so cross-platform or OS version problems largely disappear.

But now you're sending every frame pixel by pixel to the user. (And MPEG-4 isn't great when compressing visualization rather than video.)

And you've got a network latency delay on every keystroke, or mouse click, or mouse movement.

And if tens? hundreds? thousands? of people want to use your app simultaneously, you've got to have enough server side CPU/GPU to handle that many users.

So yeah, it's complicated and expensive to implement, no matter what you choose. As well as WebRTC, you could also look at screen sharing software such as VNC. Nvidia game streaming might be a more suitable technology to explore, because there's a lot of similarity between 3D games and 3D visualisation, but don't expect it to be a magic bullet.

Have you looked at WebGL? It's the slightly cut down EGL version of OpenGL for JavaScript. If you're not making heavy use of advanced OpenGL 4 capabilities, a lot of OpenGL C/C++ code translates without too much difficulty into JavaScript and WebGL. And just about every web browser on the planet runs WebGL, even if (like Apple) the platform manufacturer discourages regular OpenGL.
The big advantage is that all the rendering and interactivity happens on the client, so latency is not a problem and you're not paying for the CPU/GPU if lots of people want to run it at the same time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Hugh-Fisher. I am aware of WebGL, but this will not work for me because we deal with a very large amount of data, and sending this data to the client just wouldn't work. Plus, it will still require strong GPU in the client, which may be a limitation.
The problem with Nvidia GameStream is that it sounds like it is taiolored to games, and looks like it is not designed for the cloud.